# How to get devices IP address in Windows IoT C#

Tags: networking, windows-iot

using Raspberry Pi 2.
have Windows Iot installed.

I am trying to get the devices DHCP address via my C# code.

At the moment I have this:

```
 var hostName = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
```

Whilst I can read the 'DisplayName' but the IP Address Info is always null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to use this code

```
public IPAddress GetIPAddress()
{
   List<string> IpAddress = new List<string>();
   var Hosts = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames().ToList();
   foreach (var Host in Hosts)
   {
      string IP = Host.DisplayName;
      IpAddress.Add(IP);
   }
   IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress.Last());
   return address;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I upgraded to IoT Windows 10 Build 10586 and now the broadcasts are not received. Has this new OS version got a firewall somewhere now?

Comment: Hi. Not sure mate. Please ask a new question. I will inspect. Check if u can ping the port 80 and your in question.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded ppumkin code to return ipv4 address if exists. Returns null if disconnected or not available.
(the original code returns ipv6 for me on rasberry pi 3)

```
    using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;

    public IPAddress GetIpAddress()
    {
        var hosts = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
        foreach (var host in hosts)
        {
            IPAddress addr;
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(host.DisplayName, out addr)) continue;
            if (addr.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork) continue;
            return addr;
        }
        return null;
    }
```